# Changing stylesheet url using .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I want the url:

```
http://localhost/application/cms/css/style.css
```

To go to

```
/application/www/cms/css/style.css
```

Where the 'application' folder is my root, where my .htaccess file and index.php are located. How would I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enable mod_rewrite and .htaccess through httpd.conf and then put this code in your .htaccess under DOCUMENT_ROOT directory:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^(application)/([^/]+/css/style\.css)$ /$1/www/$2 [R,L,NC]
```

Comment: Cool, now I want cms to be dynamic, how would I do that?